# the return type is incompatible with Asynctask

Tags: android, string, android-asynctask

I'm trying to capture the response of httpclient using AsyncTask but throws me the following error verifying any incompatibility doInBackground in the String:

"the return type is incompatible with AsyncTask"

I try to capture the string of response of httpclient and return it in doInBackground for to use this in onPostExecute.

Someone could help me.

Thank you

```
private String insertar(){  
            String response = "";
            HttpClient httpclient;
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
            HttpPost httppost;
            httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost= new HttpPost("http://10.1.1.20/pruebaAndroid/insert.php"); // Url del Servidor      
            //Añadimos nuestros datos
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dni",dni.getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nombre",nombre.getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("telefono",telefono.getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email.getText().toString().trim()));

            try {
               httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));// envio las variables

               // capturo lo que devuelve, si no devolviera nada solo hago la ejecucion del httpclient sin el handler

               ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler(); 
               response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

               //----------------------------------------------------------------

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return response;
        }
```

This is AsyncTask:

```
//AsyncTask para insertar Personas
    class Insertar extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>{

        private Activity context;

        Insertar(Activity context){
            this.context=context;
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            String result = insertar();

            return result;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: post the declaration of the AsyncTask.

Comment: var is declarate up like String

Comment: ok, but still, `post the declaration of the AsyncTask.` (funny how whenever one says more than 1 things, all but the last are instantly dismissed) (it's something apparently everybody does)

Comment: check up my edit code with my AsyncTask complete

Comment: the way you defined your asynctask, `doInBackground` must return a Boolean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem here is that AsyncTask Extensions are generic and need three types: `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`AsyncTask which may be Void or a class, but not primitive data types.

so what happens is you told the compiler that doInBackground returns a primitive var but it was expecting an instance of the class `String`.

So use  `doInBackground` function as

```
@Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                String result = insertar();

                return result;
            }
```

**Edit**

In AsyncTask you are returning `Boolean` and in doInBackground return type is `String`,so

change it to `String` because you want String value from `insertar()` function,i.e. change

```
class Insertar extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>{
```

to

```
class Insertar extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
```

and

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        }
```

to

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }
```

Comment: @user3810167 Is var is "string" instead of "String",please post full asynctask code.

Comment: @user3810167 Happy to help,enjoy coding.